# Setting the default OS ABI for gdb?

Tags: gdb

Every time I try to run my MINGW64 (Windows 10) `gdb` on an ARM .elf, I get this message:

```
$ gdb-multiarch --batch -ex 'set osabi none' my_ARM.elf

warning: A handler for the OS ABI "Windows" is not built into this configuration
of GDB.  Attempting to continue with the default armv6s-m settings.
```

I find this warning message EXTREMELY irritating, and I would like to stop getting it printed, but not by just redirecting stderr to `2>/dev/null`.

So, as you can see in the above command, I've tried to execute `set osabi none`, but that did not help - warning  message still appears.

If I try to inspect inside `gdb` shell, I can see:

```
(gdb) help set osabi
Set OS ABI of target.

(gdb) help show osabi
Show OS ABI of target.

(gdb) show osabi
The current OS ABI is "none".
The default OS ABI is "Windows".

(gdb) set osabi
Requires an argument. Valid arguments are auto, default, none, GNU/Linux, Newlib, FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD, PikeOS, WindowsCE, Darwin, DICOS, GNU/Hurd, DJGPP, QNX-Neutrino, Solaris, SVR4, Windows, Cygwin, AIX, LynxOS178, OpenVMS, SDE.
```

So, the `set osabi none` was likely accepted - but I get the complaint due to the "default OS ABI"?

So, I guess, if I can somehow set the "default OS ABI" to something else, then the warning message will disappear. But how do I change the "default OS ABI"?

I (think I) found the mailing list announcement for this feature (21 years ago!): [RFC: "set osabi"](https://gdb-patches.sourceware.narkive.com/VstuX7lw/rfc-set-osabi) - and a brief look there, implies that the "default OS ABI" is a compile-time decision, and I cannot change it at runtime. Is that still true?

So, my question is: how can I change the "default OS ABI" for `gdb` at program start, if it is possible - and if not, are there ways to stop the above warning message appearing, without hacks like piping entire stderr to `/dev/null`?

Comment: Try `-iex` instead of `-ex`, the `-ex` commands are run after the executable is loaded into GDB, so I suspect after the warning has been emitted, this is so things like `gdb -ex 'break some_func' -ex 'run' ./prog` will work as expected.